# How to interchange the key value output of app.url_map.iter_rules function

Tags: python, json, rest, flask

I have this python code which gives me all the api routes along with details in a JSON format when I hit the API GET request on http://localhost:9985/api/help

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/myapi', methods = ['GET'])
def this_func():
    """ /read"""
    return jsonify({})

@app.route('/api/help', methods = ['GET'])
def help():
    """ /write"""
    func_list = {}
    for rule in app.url_map.iter_rules():
        if rule.endpoint != 'static':
            func_list[rule.rule] = app.view_functions[rule.endpoint].__doc__
    return jsonify(func_list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(host='localhost', port=9985)
```

Output of this gives me:

```
{
  "/api/help": "/write",
  "/myapi": "/read"
}
```

I want to have the position of key and value interchanged which means I want the output to look like:

```
{
  "/write": "/api/help",
  "/read": "/myapi"
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I am sorry I did not get the question

Comment: Does `func_list[app.view_functions[rule.endpoint].__doc__] = rule.rule` fix the problem?

Comment: @lord63.j no it gave me error TypeError: unorderable types: str() &lt; NoneType()

Comment: @lovesoftlayeraj: then please post the full traceback for that error. You don't have any `<` comparisons in your posted code.

Comment: http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/129/ This is exactly what I have in my application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just swap the key and the value then; make `rule.rule` the value for each `__doc__` key:

```
if rule.endpoint != 'static':
    docstring = app.view_functions[rule.endpoint].__doc__
    if docstring is not None and docstring.strip():
        func_list[docstring.strip()] = rule.rule
```

It may be that not *all* your routes have a docstring, so do test for that. I also used the `str.strip()` method to remove the extra whitespace you have in your docstrings. You may also want to limit this to the first line only:

```
if docstring is not None and docstring.strip():
    func_list[docstring.partition('\n')[0].strip()] = rule.rule
```

Note that `func_list` is a misleading name for a dictionary.

Comment: this worked perfectly but I still have those extra spaces. The strip command doesn't work. This is my stack trace          File "/root/Python-3.5.0/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/root//app-develop/test.py", line 18, in help
    if docstring.strip():                                                                                   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked awesome!  One last question - In my original application I have all my routes tagged as                        api.route('/read/', methods=['GET'])
In this test script I have app.route('/read/', methods=['GET'])                                                      How can I modify this script to work with api.route instead of app.route where app = Flask(___name___)
 and api is an import I have in my original application.

Comment: I can't answer that as that depends entirely on the type of object of `api`.

Comment: http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/129/ This is exactly what I have and I want to iterate over urls map for several such APIs and save into a json structure

Comment: That uses Flask Restful, and the API object is then an instance of `flask_restful.Api`.

Comment: app = Flask(__name__)
from .api_1 import api as api_blueprint
app.register_blueprint(api_blueprint) this is my api object its a blueprint and not a restful api object

Comment: @lovesoftlayeraj: blueprints collect all `route()` calls into a deferred state, then when you use `app.register_blueprint(api_blueprint)` all `api.route()` calls are 'replayed' to the `Flask` object. Other than that, all that happens is that the routes are prefixed with the blueprint prefix; they are regular routes just like `app.route()` calls give you. My code in my answer works for those just as well.

Comment: So do you mean I should simple copy this code with app.route in my apiroutes.py file where all my APIs are defined with api.route annotation? Which means my Python file will have all APIs annotated as api.route except this one with app.route annotation? If yes how to initialise app in my Python file ? I don't have any app object there ..Thanks a ton!

Comment: @lovesoftlayeraj: because your `help` route can only be called after your `api` blueprint has been properly registered, it should just work, yes.

Comment: I got this                                                                                                       File "/root/python/api/apiroutes.py",                                                                       line 26, in <module>
    @app.route('/api/help', methods = ['GET'])
NameError: name 'app' is not defined

Comment: @lovesoftlayeraj: yes, you still need to import `app` to get to the name.

Comment: I imported app and then the added api with app.route('/api/help', methods = ['GET']). I got 404 error. Looks like will have to register this in blueprint? If I change to api.route I get  a blank json response as all my other APIs have api,route as annotation and not app.route so that means this function only reads apis defined with app.route tag.

Comment: @lovesoftlayeraj: we are really stretching the comments to breaking point here. Perhaps it is time to post a new question instead?

Comment: Sure I have another thread. Also invited you to a chat http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36516408/how-to-iterate-over-api-routes-in-a-different-file-than-the-app-initialization-f